# Python pdb.set_trace() gets ignored in terminal but working in IPython?

Tags: python, pdb

I am trying to debug a program that returns the longest ascending subarray in a parent array. The following is the program file named *longest.py*.

The problem is when I run `python longest.py` in command line, no prompts from `pdb` was shown. However, I was excepting some prompts because I used `pdb.set_trace()` statements in a few places.

```
import pdb

def longest(array):
    pdb.set_trace()
    size = len(array)
    if size == 1:
        pdb.set_trace()
        return 1
    else:
        pdb.set_trace()
        print('Currently looking at subarray of length: ')
        print(size)
        if array[-1] > array[-2]: 
            pdb.set_trace()
            return longest(array[0:size-1]) + 1   # increasing the number by 1
        else:
            return longest(array[0:size-1])

def main():
    a = [7, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 9, 6]
    longest(a)

if __name__  == 'main':
    main()
```

On the other hand, this following program, put in a Jupyter Notebook cell and run it, does gives desired pdb prompts.

```
a = [7, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 9, 6]

import pdb

# recursive version
def longest(array):
    size = len(array)
    pdb.set_trace()
    if size == 1:
        pdb.set_trace()
        return 1
    else:
        pdb.set_trace()
        print('Currently looking at subarray of length: ')
        print(size)
        if array[-1] > array[-2]: 
            return longest(array[0:size-1]) + 1   # increasing the number by 1
        else:
            return longest(array[0:size-1])

longest(a)
```

My questions are:
1) Why pdb.set_trace() seems to be ignored in the first scenario, and 
2) Why pdb.set_trace() works in the second scenario?

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Updates 20 minutes later**

I pasted the second program into a python file *longest2.py* and run it from command line. pdb works fine there.

So I guess the problem with the first file is not with pdb but my "main" function? Still haven't figured it out...

Comment: simple typo: your missing the "dunder" syntax for the `__main__` method. change `if __name__  == 'main':` to `if __name__  == '__main__':` and it should work

Comment: @davedwards Thanks! It's working now. I realized I did not understand `__main__`  after all, but it's good to know!